# Somar índices de um vetor respeitando condição

Tags: python-2.7

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
import random

usuarios = 2
APs = 2
distancias = random.sample(range(0, 100), usuarios*APs)
teste = [sum(distancias[x: x + usuarios]) for x in range(0, len(distancias), usuarios)]

print(teste)
```

Esse código cria um vetor com o tamanho da multiplicação dos APs com os usuarios e depois efetua a soma de 2 em 2 e salva no vetor teste..

Por exemplo:

- Digamos que o vetor seja assim:

  distancias = [10, 20, 40, 60]
- O resultado ficará assim:

  teste = [30, 100]

Porém, o que desejo é que a soma seja efetuada somente dos valores menores que 50, caso seja maior, o valor é atribuído à soma anterior ou posterior..

Por exemplo:

Nos valores dados acima a resposta deveria ser:

```
teste = [90, 40]
```

- Percebam que o valor 60 foi somado a parte somada anteriormente, pois ele é maior que 50.

Desculpa caso não tenha sido muito claro, tentei ser o máximo possível.

Alguém, pode me ajudar com esse problema? Não consigo prosseguir.

Comment: Até a parte de somar dois a dois ficou claro, mas a de somar menores que 50 não. Por quê no exemplo foi somado 10, 20 e 60 e o 40 não? O 40 é menor que 50, então ele não deveria ser somado junto? Aliás, o que está tentando resolver? Tente descrever o problema e não só a solução que tentou, pois talvez esta bem seja a melhor saída.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o melhor para voce seria transformar o array em um array de 2 dimensoes e entao somar os pares.

Um exemplo usando numpy:

```
import random
import numpy as np

# tamanho de cada um dos novos arrays pequenos
usuarios = 2
# convertendo em um array do numpy
distancias = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print("distancias = ")
print(distancias)
# transformando o array de 10 valores em um array de 5 valores
# onde cada um desses valores eh um array com 2 valores
matrix = distancias.reshape((distancias.size // usuarios),usuarios)
print("matrix = ")
print(matrix)
# soma cada um desses arrays pequenos, 
# criando um array array das somas
nova = matrix.sum(axis=1)
print("nova = ")
print(nova) # [ 3  7 11 15 19]
```

Voce pode ver esse exemplo sendo executado aqui:
https://repl.it/@thiagodamata/GiddyPettyAmurratsnake